# How do I combine multiple branches and reduce the number of branches in git?

Tags: git, branch

I have many branches that are all about implementation of tags. My branches are:
 ms-tags-v1
 ms-tags-v2
 ms-tags-v3

I would like to combine these branches into 1 single git branch named:
 ms-tags

How do I go about it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Withou knowing anything about the structure or relationship between the three branches, I can suggest that create your target branch from the first one, and then merge the other two into it:

```
git checkout ms-tags-v1
git checkout -b ms-tags   # create branch 'ms-tags' from 'ms-tags-v1'
git merge ms-tags-v2      # merge 'ms-tags-v2'
git merge ms-tags-v3      # merge 'ms-tags-v3'
```

If you reveal the exact relationship between the three branches, a nicer option might be available.